# How to solve problem with mapbox addMarker in Android

Tags: android, mapbox

```
private fun onMapReady() {
        mapView.getMapboxMap().setCamera(
            CameraOptions.Builder()
                .zoom(14.0)
                .build()
        )
        mapView.getMapboxMap().loadStyleUri(
            Style.MAPBOX_STREETS
        ) {
            initLocationComponent()
            setupGesturesListener()
        }

        val icon = IconFactory.getInstance(requireContext()).fromResource(R.drawable.ic_marker_uchebnoye)
        val marker = mapView.getMapboxMap().addMarker(
            MarkerOptions()
                .position(LatLng(51.50550, -0.07520))
                .icon(icon)
                .title("MarkerName")
                .snippet("MarkerDescription")
        )
    }
```

This is my onMapReady function, i am trying to add marker on my map, but everytime i call addMarker it is marked as red in IDE.

This is my dependencies connected with mapbox:

```
implementation 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-sdk:9.0.0'
implementation 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-sdk-services:5.8.0'
implementation 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-sdk-geojson:5.8.0'
implementation 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-sdk-turf:5.8.0'
implementation 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-sdk-plugins:5.8.0'
implementation 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-plugin-annotation-v9:0.9.0'
```

Tryed to remake imports, changing version, nothing helped.

Comment: You should add more details.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.